# Finding the critical population level

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

From this equation

N_(t+1)=((1/a)((N_(t))^(-b))(lambda*N_(t)),

where the term in the first bracket represents the fraction of the population N_(t) that survives to generation t+1 whilst the second term represents the number of progeny at generation t.

The coefficients a and b are both positive whilst lambda, the reproductive rate, is greater than one.

The question is:
The model does not make sense when the fraction of survivors is greater than one. Find the critical population level, N_(c), below which this happens. (N_(c) should be expressed in terms of a and b).

So I've tried figuring out the critical points and I've found these partials:

f_(a)=(-lambda*((N_(t))^(1-b)))/(a^2)

f_(b)=((-lambda*((N_(t))^(1-b))ln(N))/a

I'm not sure if this is the way to go?...